# Determinant of matrix with asymptotic expansion

Tags: matrix, series-expansion, asymptotics

i have determinant which each element have asymptotic expansion.

$\begin{bmatrix}1+5/s+6/s^3+O[1/s^4] & 1+8/s+4/s^2+O[1/s^4]\\1+2/s+2/s^3+O[1/s^4] & 1-1/s+8/s^3+O[1/s^4]\end{bmatrix}$

```
M = ({
   {1 + 5/s + 6/s^3 + O[1/s]^4, 1 + 8/s + 4/s^2 + O[1/s]^4},
   {1 + 2/s + 2/s^3 + O[1/s]^4, 1 - 1/s + 8/s^3 + O[1/s]^4}
  }
```

when calculating determinant, Mathematica returned an expression that had a O[1/s^6] in it.

```
48/s^6-8/s^5+18/s^4+4/s^3-25/s^2-6/s+(12 (O[1/s]^1)^4)/s^3-(4 (O[1/s]^1)^4)/s^2-(6 (O[1/s]^1)^4)/s
```

I want the result to show up to $O[1/s^4]$. How can i do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`O`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/O) representation of an expansion point of [`Infinity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Infinity) is obtained with:

```
O[x, Infinity]
```

*(see this part of the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/O.html#19685) for [`O`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/O))*.

So, you just need to do:

```
M = {
    {1+5/s+6/s^3+O[s,Infinity]^4,1+8/s+4/s^2+O[s,Infinity]^4},
    {1+2/s+2/s^3+O[s,Infinity]^4,1-1/s+8/s^3+O[s,Infinity]^4}
};

Det[M] //TeXForm
```

> $-\frac{6}{s}-\frac{25}{s^2}+\frac{4}{s^3}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{s}\right)^4\right)$

Comment: thank you for solution.

Comment: Good answer.  But the `O[1/s]` notation is also used for other infinities (`-Infinity`, `ComplexInfinity`, etc.) with no visible difference.  When in doubt, look at the `InputForm` for the result to know which infinity is being used.

Answer (score 1):

You may notice that `SeriesData` issues a message when you define this matrix. It's not recognizing `1/s` as a valid variable, which is why `O[1/s]` doesn't work as advertised.

A quick and dirty fix is to just replace `s` with `1/invS` and then replace it back after `Det`:

```
Det[M /. s -> 1/invS] /. invS -> 1/s
```

> -(6/s)-25 (1/s)^2+4 (1/s)^3+O[1/s]^4

*Edit*:

It seems like you can get reciprocal powers like so:

```
SeriesData[s, Infinity, {1, 5, 0, 6}, 0, 4, 1]
```

> 1+5/s+6/s^3+O[1/s]^4

This series representation should obey series arithmetic correctly. I don't really understand why that output doesn't work when used as normal input, though.

Comment: thank you so much.

Comment: @cabri61 No problem. I think you may have hit some sort of strange idiosyncrasy of the `SeriesData` system. I updated the answer with an example of how to get reciprocal powers working correctly.